# PhotonNetwork does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I have the latest version of unity and I'm using Photon for real-time multiplayer. However, I've encountered this issue, could someone help me?

Assets/Script/Launcher.cs(41,13): error CS0103: The name `PhotonNetwork' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Please add your code. Nobody can figure out what's wrong without seeing what you wrote.

Comment: I've fixed the issue but, thank you!

Comment: Answer your own question then

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change package, by changing from PUN2 to Classic. The switch has solved all errors which have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this error, but in my case, it's silly mistake by me. I forgot below lines in starting of my page and started access Photon things.

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
```